# React.js broke dispatchEvent

Tags: reactjs, onclick, dispatchevent

for example:

I add event handler in react:

```
<div onClick={someHandler}/>
```

Then I dispatch event:

```
let clickEvt = new MouseEvent('click', {
    'bubbles': false,
    'cancelable': true
});

elm.dispatchEvent(clickEvt);
```

But nothing happens. I hear you can use `elm.click()` to trigger the react event. I'm wondering if that is the proper way to do it in react? Also what is the difference between `click()` and `dispatchEvent()`? Because I kinda want to stick to `dispatchEvent()`.

Comment: What is the value of `elm`?

Comment: It is a HTMLnode I retrieve by using getElementsByTagName('button')[idx], the button should exist, otherwise it should say somthing like elm is undefined.

Comment: @felix I just double checked, `elm` is logged as the right button before `dispatchEvent` is called. When I click the button with my mouse, everything works fine, but `dispatchEvent` does nothing. Sorry I used `div` in example, but it's a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All

I figured it out. `bubbles` must be set to `true` for react to receive the event, which is why `click()` method works, because it automatically bubbles.