# Javascript cannot manually dispatch mouse event of react-rendered buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mouseevent

I have two buttons, one rendered by React and one by plain HTML, which have the same handlers for `mousedown` and `mouseup`. Though they works correctly upon clicking, when I try to manually dispatch `mousedown` and `mouseup` events manually (by `.dispatch(new MouseEvent)`), only the HTML one receives the event, while the React one does not. There are no errors thrown in the process, and dispatching events on either button returns `true`.

I have made a simple [CodePen](https://codepen.io/fhfuih/pen/MZGzBR) to illustrate my problem.

There are two buttons in the pen, one rendered by React and one by plain HTML, the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events of which are set to have simple visual effects. Manual dispatching can be done by pressing spacebar.

My environment is the latest Vivaldi with JavaScript engine `V8 7.1.302.31`

Expecting the React button to receive the dispatched event and behave just like being clicked as well.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43098550/react-js-broke-dispatchevent)

I have to set `bubbles: true` upon constructing the event. An [example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent#Example) uses the following three options

```
new MouseEvent("mousedown", {
  bubbles: true,
  cancelable: true,
  view: window
})
```